# How to solve Tableview data array "Out of range values" using Swift 4?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, tableview

My scenario I am using multiple array's for multiple cell label's. Per cell two different label's I am maintaining. I assigned separate array's for cell labels.

Like:

```
cell.accessibilityValue = String(id[indexPath.row])
cell.name_Label.text = name[indexPath.row]
cell.city_Label.text = city[indexPath.row]
```

here, all array values I am getting from my JSON and appending separately. Only name and city I am going to show but cell.accessibilityValue "ID" I am trying to store that ID within `cell.accessibilityValue` because I am maintaining two buttons within cell `ADD` and `Plus`. First Add will show, once user clicked that add button, It will call JSON and get ID values after that only ID values appending within `cell.accessibilityValue = String(id[indexPath.row])` then reloading also I will.

Issues I am facing:

1. Initially no values in
   `cell.accessibilityValue = String(id[indexPath.row])` so I am
   getting out of range error.
2. After add button I am trying to append the ID values into id array
   and it should assign into my cell because after add clicked it will
   hide and plus button will be display, for plus button click to get
   that stored ID.

NOTE: here ID may have chance to come null, so if values available need to assign otherwise null.

Here my code

```
protocol CustomCellDelegate {
    func cellButtonTapped(cell: CustomOneCell)
}

class CustomOneCell: UITableViewCell {

    // Link those IBOutlets with the UILabels in your .XIB file
    @IBOutlet weak var name_Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var city_Label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var add_Button: UIButton!

    var delegate: CustomCellDelegate?

    @IBAction func add_buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        delegate?.cellButtonTapped(cell: self)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, CustomCellDelegate {

    var id = [Int]()        // This is from JSON but Initially no values
    var name = [String]()   // This is from JSON ["Item 1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]
    var city = [String]()   // This is from JSON ["Item 1", "Item2", "Item3", "Item4"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    //MARK - UITableview
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return name.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CustomCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomOneCell

        cell.delegate = self
        cell.accessibilityValue = String(id[indexPath.row]) // #1. Initially no values, So I am getting out of range Error

        cell.name_Label.text = name[indexPath.row]
        cell.city_Label.text = city[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func cellButtonTapped(cell: CustomOneCell) {

        let url = URL(string: "")!
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
            guard let data = data else {
                print("request failed \(error)")
                return
            }
            do {
                if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [[String: Any]] {
                    for item in json {

                        let id = item["id"]!
                        self.id.append(id as! Int) // #2. After table load I am appending some values into id array
                    }
                    //Table reload to assign id values
                }
            } catch let parseError {
                print("parsing error: \(parseError)")
                let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
                print("raw response: \(responseString!)")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

    }
```

Comment: It seems to be so valid to get such an error. Are you sure that the count for the three arrays are the same? Furthermore, I would *highly* recommend to group your data together in a *Model* (one model contains id, name and city) instead of getting them as separated arrays.

Comment: Initially no values, So I am getting out of range Error in ID but other two arrays data will be avilable. @Ahmad

Comment: *I am using multiple array's*. This causes the error. As Joakim suggested use a struct. It's much more efficient and easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way forward is to add a range check in `tableView:cellForRowAt`

```
if indexPath.row < id.count {
    cell.accessibilityValue = String(id[indexPath.row])
}
```

But if it is possible I would look into creating a struct with all three values and maintaining one instead of three arrays

```
struct SomeData {
    var id: Int
    var name: String
    var city: String
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, I know struct is a easy way but I implemented many lines of code, So unable to modify again. I will try with your solution and let it know result here. Thank you @Joakim Danielson